# Fetch JSON object with API link by PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I'm struggling to get JSON object with API link by PHP. (http://hots.adspreemedia.com/api/characters). This link should allow me to fetch a list of characters as JSON object.

What I tried was the following code.

```
<?php
$list = file_get_contents('http://hots.adspreemedia.com/api/characters');
echo $list;
?>
```

But it just shows only `{"status":"200","message":"OK","data":[1,2,3,4]}` in my localhost. My final goal is to create a list of characters in PHP file.

Comment: That's a JSON string, you can use `json_decode()` to convert it to a PHP object or array. But this doesn't seem to have anything to do with getting a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the link you posted. it matches exactly what you are getting back.

To get more data, you will need to follow their api docs for retrieving more info from them

Is this a site you are building? there is no sigup form, and no documentation I can find without logging in to help you with

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch [1,2,3,4] then do following

```
$list=json_decode($list,true);
$chars=$list['data']; //-- The array of characters
```